# Pointer Fun in C. Why won't this compile?

Tags: c, pointers

I always thought I was an intelligent person until I started learning programming.  This is a small example of something that wouldn't compile

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char* dictionary;
  dictionary = malloc(sizeof(char) * 3);
  *dictionary = "ab";
  char c = dictionary[0];
  int i = 0;
  while (c != "b")
  {
    printf("%c\n", c);
    i++;
    c = dictionary[i];
  }
}
```

error.c:8:15: error: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to
      'char' from 'char [3]'  *dictionary = "ab";

error.c:11:12: error: result of comparison against a string literal is
      unspecified (use strncmp instead)  while (c != "b")

error.c:11:12: error: comparison between pointer and integer
      ('int' and 'char *')  while (c != "b")

Comment: What compiler error are you getting? The only thing I can notice is that you do not have a return for your `main` function

Comment: If you declare main to return `int`, please do return an int at the end...

Comment: Among other things, in the `while` condition since you're comparing a single `char` value, use single quotes like this: `while (c != 'b')`. The double quotes create a string literal, the value of which is a pointer and not something you want to compare against.

Comment: `*dictionary = "ab";`? Nope, `dictionary` is a `char*`, not a `char**`.

Comment: @JohnOdom GCC gives `assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast` and `comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]`

Comment: Watch out for this `dictionary = "ab"` assignment.  This is not what you're expecting (`strcpy( dictionary, "ab" )` is probably what you want).

Comment: doing cs50 using clang to compile, main returns 0 if not specified otherwise.  EOF, if I knew what that meant, that would probably answer my question.  I'll keep studying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with the single quotes in the while, you cannot do *dictionary = "ab".

When you dereference a char * (by doing *dictionary) the result is a single char.  You can initialize a char * to point to a string though.  That would be if you do all in one line:

```
char *dictionary = "ab";
```

Otherwise, you should do:

```
#include <string.h>

strcpy(dictionary, "ab");
```

Comment: This is the understanding I was lacking.  I thought by doing *dictionary = "ab" I was going to the memory I allocated and put a string of chars there.

Answer (score 1):

You're codes are not correct. Not even a little.. kinda makes me think it's a homework assignment.. but here's a few hints.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char* dictionary;
  dictionary = malloc(sizeof(char) * 3); /* ok, I expect to see a free later */
  *dictionary = "ab"; /* assigning a string literal to a dereferenced char *..
                      /* maybe we should use strncpy..  */
  char c = dictionary[0];
  int i = 0;
  while (c != "b") /* hmm.. double quotes are string literals.. maybe you mean 'b' */
  {
    printf("%c\n", c);
    i++;
    c = dictionary[i];
  }
  /* hmm.. still no free, guess we don't need those 3 bytes.
     int return type.. probably should return 0 */
}
```

Comment: You should use c comments rather than c++.  Not all c compilers can handle //

Comment: Playing devil's advocate and in OP's defense: Most OS kernel developers frown upon programs that upon exit go through all the work to free their stuff. Just terminate the program already. If you go through the trouble of explicitly deallocating, you're just forcing the OS to swap in all the pages the memory points to.

Comment: @Beirdo: assuming C99 `//` is valid even if it's not C++

Comment: datenwolf, thank you but I was taught to free memory or it's a leak.  I was just looking for the shortest bit of code to illustrate my problem

Comment: Yes, but for quite a few compilers c99 is an option, not the default.  Best not to complicate the lives of c newbies any more than it already will be, no?